# Automatic build is not happening in jenkins from git

Tags: git, jenkins

In jenkins I ticked the 'Build when a change is pushed to git hub' but still it don't automatically build when I push the change to the git repo url.

Comment: Looking at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/37749162/gconfig.png for https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-TriggerabuildwhenachangeispushedtoGitHub, did you click on "Test Credential" button? Does it work?

Comment: Where I can find that test credential buttion? Does it need any additional plugins?

Comment: You would find it only if you have installed the GitHub plugin in your Jenkins server. Do you have that plugin in place?

Comment: Ya I found that. But the problem is that there is no username or password since the server repo is also a networked local system in our organization.

Comment: So... it has *nothing* to do with GitHub then?

Comment: If I am using such a project am I not able to automate the build when push happens?

Answer (score 1):

For repos managed locally (ie not on github.com), the [Git plugin recommends](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository):

> To minimize the delay between a push and a build, it is recommended to set up the post-receive hook in the repository to poke Jenkins when a new commit is made.
>   To do this, add the following line in your hooks/post-receive where "URL of the Git repository" is the fully URL you use to clone this repository.

```
curl http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>[&branches=branch1[,branch2]*][&sha1=<commit ID>]
```

So you need to add a hook to your target repo, in order for that hook to call Jenkins.

Comment: now my url is \\PC02\test\adempiere370.git. So what am I suppose to give in the git url field in order to add that hook?

Comment: @TonyDavis the hook is added directly in \\PC02\test\adempiere370.git\hooks\post-receive: that hook calls Jenkins, not the contrary.

Comment: I have found that this poke combined with an hourly pull works well if the network connection between Jenkins server and git host is not 100% reliable.

Comment: @VonC Providing \\PC02\test\adempiere370.git\hooks\post-receive as url givs build error.

Comment: @TonyDavis no, the url remain `\\PC02\test\adempiere370.git` in your Jenkins job. I meant, you have, independently of Jenkins, to create the hook in the `\\PC02\test\adempiere370.git\hooks\post-receive` script, in order for said script to trigger the build, by calling Jenkins. Jenkins ignores everything about that hook. All that Jenkins knows is the repo to get the sources from.

Comment: i add "# curl http://se03:8080/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=\\PC02\test\adempiere370.git[&branches=branch1[,branch2]*][&sha1=<commit ID>]" in hook/post-receive.sample directory of Repo. But still automatic build not happening!

Comment: @TonyDavis You did replace `branch1` by the branch you want to monitor, right?: and remove the `[]`: it is a syntax to give you an example of the kind of uri to call.

Comment: @VonC Thanks alot for the kind replay! Yes, we did what you mentioned. But still automation not happening!Here below what we done! "# curl http://se03:8080/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=\\PC02\test\adempiere370.git[&branches=master*][&sha1=<commit ID>]"

Comment: @TonyDavis so... why ro I still see `[` and `]` in your url? For you, I would recommend:  `curl http://se03:8080/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=\\PC02\test\adempiere370.git&branc‌​hes=master`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48567/discussion-between-tony-davis-and-vonc)